# Open & close default browser in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, browser

I am trying to launch a URL in the default web browser and then close it after "x" time.

To open it I am using Process.Start(url) but can't figure out how to close it.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got the `Process.Kill()` method which cater for this.

Comment: But how would I know which browser they are using?